# Extract a table/matrix from R into Excel with same colors and stle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created this matrix using ggplot

[image]

How can I extract an editable table into excel with same colors to adjust?

Could my question look a bit silly, I am a newbie in R, I don't have much experience. Is there a straightforward way to extract a colored table into Excel?

Thank you so much in advance